# Como chamar uma animação através do comando onclick - HTML + JS

Tags: css

Boa tarde! Sou novato na linguagem, estou tentando resolver um problema utilizando o comando onclick para chamar uma animação. Acontece que não consigo fazer o onclick funcionar de maneira alguma, muito menos **iniciar/parar** a animação. Segue meu código para análise:

```
<div class="resposta3">
    <div id="balao" onclick="voar()" onclick="stop()">
        <img src="images/ex3/balao.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       var mexendo = document.getElementById('balao');
       function mexer() {
          mexendo.classList.toggle("voar");
       }
       function stop() {
          mexendo.classList.remove("voar");
       }
   </script>
</div>
```

Segue também a parte da animação e css:

```
.resposta3{
  border: solid black 3px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(../images/ex3/fundo.png);
}

#balao{
  animation: voar 1s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes voar {
  0%{
    margin-top: -50px;
  }

  100%{
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

Se puderem me ajudar ficarei muito grato. Obrigado

Comment: Os nomes dos seus métodos estao errados. Voce está chamando `voar()`, sendo que no seu javascript existe o `mexer()`.

Comment: Tem vários problemas no seu código, vc tem dois eventos **onclick** no mesmo elemento Html, em um deles está chamando uma função **voar()**, mas, no script não tem essa função!

Comment: Outro problema mencionado pelo @LeAndrade, é que há dois eventos `onclick` na sua `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Por estar aprendendo a linguagem seu código possui diversos erros, não se deve conter dois ou mais do mesmo **evento** Javascript em um elemento `Html` como fez no **`onclick`** e também do jeito que fez no `Css` a animação já está inserida na div e no script vc está chamando a animação em si e não uma classe:

```js
var balao = document.getElementById('balao');
var mexer = false;           // variavel de controle de clique no botao

function action() {
  mexer = !mexer;            // nega o valor conforme o clique no botao
  
  if(mexer) balao.classList.toggle('voando');
  else balao.classList.remove('voando');
}
```

```css
.resposta3 {
  border: solid black 3px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(../images/ex3/fundo.png);
}

.voando {
  animation: voar 1s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes voar {
  0% {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="resposta3">
  <div id="balao" onclick="action()">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a1/a8/39/a1a839b45f78793f00eeeddb752b4fc9.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```